# Finding a curve lying on a given surface

Tags: calculus, parametrization

I have a bohemian dome given by the parametric equation

$$x= a \cos u$$ $$y = b \cos v + a\sin u -1$$ $$z=c\sin v$$

, where

$$a= 0.5$$ $$b = 1.5 $$ $$c= 1$$ , and $u,v \in [0,2\pi)$ . I know that I can somehow find a curve lying on the surface by expressing $v$ in terms of $u$, meaning by using the same parametric equation but such that $v = u x$. I just don't know how to find this correlation between $u$ and $v$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what curve you want to find. On any surface there are infinitely many curves. If the correlation is given as $v=ux$, I am not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: There are so many curves on any surface that you can not  ask for a specific parametrization. You can find  for examples geodesics  if you know some differential geometry or easier just lines of equal hight like  z= const wich gives v=const. For all other curves  you just use any function v(u)

Comment: What I'm interested in is an expression, any expression, in terms of $u$ such that by replacing it with $v$ in the parametric equation of the surface it will result in a curve that lies on this surface.